# Audio streaming using Nearby Connections API

Tags: android, audio, streaming, audio-streaming

I'm trying to stream audio across several devices using the Nearby Connections API but I'm not really sure if this is really possible/recommendable.

What I want to do is broadcast the audio files (both songs stored on the phone and from apps such as Google Music, Spotify ...) to the other devices connected and so they can start playing the songs while the receive all the data chunks of the songs.

I think with the Nearby Connections API we can only send 4KB payload chunks when we call Nearby.Connections.sendReliableMessage() so what I'm doing so far is call that function as many times as required sending 4KB chunks each time until I manage to deliver the entire file.For the onMessageReceived () Listener what I do is to store all the chunks that I receive in a byte array so once all the chunks have been transferred I can play back the song from the byte array file.

With the approach I'm taking I guess I'd be able to reproduce the song once I've transferred it on its totality, but I'd like to reproduce the songs while I'm actually receiving the data chunks, and in a synchronized manner with all the devices.

Does this makes sense to you guys? Is it the right approach? Is there any other more effective way of doing this? (I already know about the option of streaming audio using Wifi-Direct, but I'd like to use Nearby)

Answer (score 0):

The guy in [this tutorial](http://blog.pocketjourney.wordpress.com/2008/04/04/tutorial-custom-media-streaming-for-androids-mediaplayer/) had a similar problem with chunks of audio.
He shows how to play the song, while the bytes are still downloaded and the audio file is built.
Maybe you can utilize the *"Incremental Media Download"*-part of the tutorial.

Quote:

> This is where the magic happens as we download media content from the the url stream until we have enough content buffered to start the MediaPlayer. We then let the MediaPlayer play in the background while we download the remaining audio. If the MediaPlayer reaches the end of the buffered audio, then we transfer any newly downloaded audio to the MediaPlayer and let it start playing again.
>
> Things get a little tricky here because:
>
> (a) The MediaPlayer seems to lock the file so we can’t simply append our content to the existing file.
>
> ...

If this doesn't work I would just use the nearby-connection to exchange IP Adresses and go for a Wifi-Direct solution.

I hope this helps and I'd love to hear what your final solution looks like!

Comment: This is a super interesting idea. Could you instead use

Answer (score 0):

I implemented this several years ago for live audio/video packets sent in a serial stream to an Android 4.0 device. It would work the same for audio (or video) packets being streamed over the Nearby connections API.

The solution was to run a http streaming server from within the Android App, then consume this using the Android media player API with its http streaming capabilities (or you can embed ExoPlayer in your app if you prefer as it also supports http streaming).

This was achieved by piping the data stream directly into a FFSERVER process running on the device. The Android NDK was used to create and manage the named pipe required as input into FFSERVER.

As this was done a few years ago I have not tested this on versions of Android 4.1+. Anyone who does this will need to adhere to the FFmpeg GPL/LGPL license when building and distributing FFSERVER.